# Installed Recomended Nvidia Graphics Driver, now Ubuntu doesn't Boot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, ubuntu-drivers

Today I tried switching my graphics driver from the Xorg X server to the recommended Nvidia graphics driver. I did so through the additional driver's GUI. It said it required a reboot after switching. After rebooting, Ubuntu would not load and I was stuck with a black screen. I launched Ubuntu into recovery mode and I ran the command terminal `nvidia-smi` and it said that there were no GPUs found. `nvidia-smi` only works when you're the Nvidia graphics drivers (using the X.Org drivers, I couldn't run the command) so I know the driver is installed but it doesn't seem to be functioning correctly. Other commands like `ubuntu-drivers` recognized my 3080 Ti just fine.

There are 2 possible solutions:

- How can I switch back to the X.Org driver.
- Fix the Nvidia driver so it works correctly.

I would prefer whichever will be quicker as I'm a student with work I  need to get done soon in my Linux distro. I am running Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Did you choose the `-open` driver?  If you did, that driver is not compatible with your video card.

Comment: I selected the proprietary one. It was the one that said “Recomended” @Terrance

Comment: Xorg is a different level of the stack to the nvidia drivers; so your question is rather unclear.  Xorg's replacement offered is Wayland; which Nvidia does not generally work well, so you likely did not replace Xorg. Nvidia offers video **kernel modules* (commonly called *drivers*) but these aren't replacements for Xorg (Xorg sits outside of the kernel in the user area of the system).  Nvidia uses Xorg generally (being the preferred option for Nvidia over Wayland).   Was it the *nouveau* kernel module you were using?  (ie. it's what you want to return to?)

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Additional Drivers doesn't show if it is installing the `-open` or not.  Really the best way to see what driver you are choosing is doing the installation with the command line.  There might be a bug in the Additional Drivers, but I don't have enough info to go off of.  But, I do know that if it is choosing the `-open` driver that it NVIDIA's Open Source driver that your system will not boot unless you have a specific video card (personal experience here ;) ).  https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/196728/en-us/ shows the supported cards for the `-open` driver.

Comment: I do agree with what @Pilot6 has stated above and to disable Secure Boot in BIOS if it isn't already disabled.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. @guiverc, thankyou for clariying the difference between Xorg, Nouveau drivers, and Nvidia drivers. I will use the website link to determine which Nvidia driver to use in the future. I will use the command line to install it as well. I was able to get my computer functioning with the Nouveau driver using the solution below. In the future I will back up before messing with graphics drivers. I will still need to get the correct Nvidia drivers installed eventually, but for now I need to focus on school work. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: The command line install for the 525 non-open driver is done by `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Boot into recovery mode, remove all nvidia -named packages or proprietary stuff
`$ dpkg --list | grep -E ^ii.*nvidia` will show you a list of installed *.deb packages, but notably NOT *.run -packages downloaded from nvidia's site.
*`$ apt-get purge package_name` will remove .deb packages.*
*`$ runfile.RUN --uninstall` - will probably remove proprietary drivers.*

b) After the above you should be back to the nouveau -driver, as you boot normally.

c) After a normal mode boot, hit the Win-key and start typing `driver` and the `Addtional drivers` should pop up, click it.

d) Select one of the driver versions available there. Try a reboot, if the OS doesn't start or has problems, then take actions (as above) and try by selecting a different one.
*NOTE: you should have all but "Source code" selected under `/Ubuntu software\` - the leftmost tab.*

Comment: The OP had already used "Addtional drivers".

Comment: Thank you @Hannu ! Your solution worked and I'm back up and running. I'd just like to add, I used apt-get purge <package name> to uninstall all the packages that were given using the search `$dpkg --list | grep -E ^ii.*nvidia`.

Comment: @mikewhatever seems as having been without first removing any remnants of earlier attempts.